# What is a good source for info on disease frequency distribution among age groups?

Tags: bioinformatics, statistics, database

I need information on the disease frequency distribution among age groups for an Android app I'm building... Hopefully I've come to the right place. Is there a good data source for this? Like a bioinformatics database?

Comment: related http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2009/downloadable-worldwide-database-of-disease-statistics?rq=1  and http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/human-disease-and-associated-phenotype-database?rq=1

Comment: I'd say this is also a bit vague in its current format, could you expand on what sort of information you are looking for.

Comment: As the title says, I'm looking for the frequency distribution among age groups...Something like what percentage of type II diabetes patients are among age 40-50. And it's not just the distribution of one specific disease, but all kinds of diseases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to study each disease individually or do a literature review.  The Online Mendelian Inheritance in Man website may be a good starting point http://www.omim.org/
The Centers for Disease Control and Prevention lists several diseases with a variety of different statistics here:  http://www.cdc.gov/DiseasesConditions/

Comment: I've been to the CDC site. I guess I can use the statistics there, but what makes it less ideal is that ages <18 are not included. I am currently working on other stuff, so please feel free to improve your answer in the next few days :) I'll accept your answer if no other better ones pop up.